# Dynamic document: WPF Combine bound text in a static inline FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, label, flowdocument

I am trying to achieve something like the follwing:

> This is a WPF Flow Document shown to
>   user.
>   This has been generated by user **Richard Richardson** at **01/01/01 23:15:00**.
>   Blah blah blah (another **466** lines)...
>   End of message.

I want this date and the user name and 466 (and another gazillion literal texts) to come from [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx)s.

I would like to declare the documnet's Runs inline, i.e. in the Xaml file.

I'd also need technicial advice (if it's not simple) in how to embed this doc in a wpf control (anything is good, was thinking of Label or TextBlock).

Note: I am using .NET 3.5.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll find what you need here: http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/  It describes a way to create a bindable Run, which you can use as illustrated in the example downloadable from the page.